# execute tzupdater tool on oracle JDKs on multiple machines

Tags: linux, oracle, automation, timezone

I want to update Oracle JDK on multiple machines using tzupdater tool. The tool is a jar file which needs to be run on the machine where JDK resides. How do I start? There are Unix, Linux and Windows machines. Getting into every machine, downloading and updating takes a lot of time. I just need some direction on how to automate the process.

Comment: Any reason this question got downvoted??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Linux and Unix machines with SSH you can use [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)

Fabric is a Python library and command-line tool for streamlining the use of SSH for application deployment or systems administration tasks.

The idea would be copy your jar file to N servers and run it locally. Fabric is capable of doing that.

Here some Fabric examples
https://github.com/bicofino/fabric-examples

For Windows I don't know how you can achieve it.